# Android Listview with sqlite and CursorAdapter

Tags: android, database, performance, sqlite, listview

After about 12 hours of work, I managed to write a working cursoradapter class with  the super fast code of the famous [Google video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) , this class fill the listview from the database, with a text and a picture per row.
But I have the feeling that I ruined google efforts for performance with the code that I added at the end of the class, to fill the text and the picture, and I can't tell the performance when ill use the real/final database... (c is also the cursor made in the activity class)
Here are the 2 subclasses:

```
    public class CursorLi extends CursorAdapter {
    LayoutInflater minflater;
    int imd;

        public CursorLi(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
            super(context, c, autoRequery);
            minflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);     
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null){           
                convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.lvitem, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.litext);
                holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fiig);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            c.moveToPosition(position);
            imd = getResources().getIdentifier(c.getString(6), "drawable", "com.example.myapp");
            dr = getResources().getDrawable(imd);
            holder.text.setText(c.getString(4));
            holder.icon.setImageDrawable(dr);
            return convertView;
        }
        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {}
        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) { return null;    }
    }

public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
    ImageView icon;
    }
```

Can you guys help me optimize the code please ?
In particular:

1. Why I had to add "c.moveToPosition(position);" ? I thought that
   cursoradapter manages the position...
2. Is there a faster way to apply the picture to the row's imageview ? I used 3 lines of code
   (the db contain the pic file name).
3. `getString` is the best way ?
4. Was it better a separate class or a subclass ? When the class was a
   separate class I didn't know how to get the cursor data for the
   `getView()` funciton, so now its a sub class of the activity and the
   cursor is globally declared.

If you want to ask me why I didn't use simplecursoradapter, because I wanted to use the google code, for performance, since the list may have 300 rows...
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. For `CursorAdapter`s, you can override only `newView` and `bindView` instead of `getView`. The default implementation of `getView` in `CursorAdapter` does `cursor.moveToPosition` for you.
2. I don't know what you mean.
3. `getString` is fine.
4. Read 1. For managing cursors, I recommend using `CursorLoader`. (See: https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html)

Your adapter should look like this.

```
public class CursorLi extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater minflater;
    private int imd;

    public CursorLi(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
        super(context, c, autoRequery);
        minflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = minflater.inflate(R.layout.lvitem, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.litext);
        holder.icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fiig);
        view.setTag(holder);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        imd = getResources().getIdentifier(c.getString(6), "drawable", "com.example.myapp");
        dr = getResources().getDrawable(imd);
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(c.getString(4));
        holder.icon.setImageDrawable(dr);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        ImageView icon;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. So why without "c.moveToPosition(position);" , getString doesn't work ?

Comment: The default implementation of `getView` in `CursorAdapter` does that for you (https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.java#L247). If you (mistakenly) override `getView`, you need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

what i do is the following :

1st - create a Bean class that holds the values of the database like the following :

```
public class MyData {
    private String text ; 
    private String imageName ; 

    // with its getter and setter methods 


}
```

2nd - when i query the database i will get a cursor , i will loop through the cursor and set the values in MyData objects 
in an ArrayList like the following :

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(....);
ArrayList<MyData> list = new ArrayList<MyData>();
MyData data = null; 
while(cursor.moveToNext()){

data = new MyData() 

data.setText(c.getString(4));
data.setImageName(c.getString(6));

list.add(data); 

}



   cursor.close() ; 

return list ;
```

3rd- i would use a BaseAdapter instead of CursorAdapter like the following :

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Mydata> list ; 
    private Activty activty ; 


    public MyAdapter (Activity activty ,ArrayList<MyData> l ){
        this.activty =activty ; 
        this.list = l ;     

    }


}
```

4th - in your getView method you get the items from the list like the following :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //.... just like you did with your PlaceHolder to initialize the views 

        String text = list.get(position) .getText();
        String imageName = list.get(position).getImageName(); 

        // here you your image inside a new thread 

        Thread trd = new Thread(new Runnable(){
             @Override
              public void run(){

                   try{
            final int drawableResource = activty .getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(imageName , "drawable", "com.example.myapp");


                     activty .runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawableResource );

                    }
                });
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        trd.run(); 


}
```

and please give me some feedback , i wrote this on notepad :P

Hope that helps .